# WidgetKit in iOS 14 and no data for Intent Handler

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have an app on iOS 14 with widgets. After the first run of the app user can add widgets to home screen and select "Edit Widget". All is fine but there could be a scenario that user didn't enter any data into the app so there's nothing to select for showing in the widgets. iOS happily presents data selection window which is just empty. Not a very friendly user interaction.
But I've noticed that one of the developers did manage to display an alert. Any idea how to do something similar?

[Link to screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKJ9T.png)

Comment: Its most likely a today extension, not a widget

Comment: No, it's a iOS 14 widget. I suspect that in that case other SiriKit intent is being used but I don't know which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your intent handler, you implement some version of `provideXCollection(for intent, with completion)` to return an array of values. That `completion` callback can also take an Error?, so provide an error and it’ll be shown in that alert.

```
func provideObjectCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Object>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let error = NSError(domain: "test", code: 666, 
                        userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "This is an error."])
    completion(nil, error)
}
```

As @adocyn discovered in the comments, if you are implementing the search term version of this method `provideXCollection(for intent, searchTerm, with completion)` then you won’t get the alert popup, you’ll get the error in the search results screen.

Comment: First thing that I’ve tried. Unfortunately what I’ve got was an empty list with „[app name] error no 1” in the background. Not even a localizedMessage content. Just error name and number

Comment: It worked for me (iOS 14.5). I added code — is that what you tried?

Comment: Yeah, a little bit better. List still shows empty (instead of the Alert) but now at least the error displays its localized content. I think that it will have to do. Still no idea how that app did the Alert thing though.

Comment: What iOS version are you on? That code I posted shows an alert for me, exactly like your screenshot.

Comment: I've tested on 14.5 and 14.7

Comment: OK. I've got it. It's the "Intent handler provides search result as the user types" option selected in the Intent editing window. It generates different metod and with that it always shows the search window.

Comment: Ah interesting, that explains it! I guess that makes some sense, because that method will be called multiple times as the user searches and it’d be awful if that popped up an alert each time. I’ll update my answer.